# Mapping of emulated mouse button - Linux

Tags: linux, mouse, xorg, trackball

**tl;dr**: How to map the physical MIDDLE button to a different key than the emulated MIDDLE button? (Emulate3Buttons)

When using the Kensington Expert Mouse as is, the 4 buttons are physical buttons to LEFT, RIGHT, MIDDLE and BACK.
To get both BACK and FORWARD a simple rebind is possible by adding an appropriate section to xorg.conf (BACK -> FORWARD and MIDDLE -> BACK)

```
┌─┬─┐    ┌─┬─┐
│M│B│    │B│F│
├─O─┤ -> ├─O─┤
│L│R│    │L│R│
└─┴─┘    └─┴─┘
```

If I now **additionally** want a MIDDLE button the man pages mention the option "Emulate3Buttons", which emulates clicking MIDDLE by pressing both LEFT and RIGHT together.

**My problem now is this:** "Emulate3Buttons" emulates a physical MIDDLE button and since I had to map MIDDLE -> BACK earlier, I will just get another BACK button.

```
┌─┬─┐
│B│F│
├─O─┤
│L│R│
└\┴/┘
  B
```

How would I go about to end up with:

```
┌─┬─┐
│B│F│
├─O─┤
│L│R│
└\┴/┘
  M
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this has already been answered and the fix even got merged to the linux codebase
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/314795/xinput-button-mapping-and-middle-button-emulation

basically what I did was create the file /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-kensington.conf (as root)

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier  "Kensington Trackball"
    Driver  "evdev"
    MatchProduct    "Kensington Expert Mouse"

    Option  "ButtonMapping" "1 8 3 4 5 6 7 9 0 2"
    Option  "Emulate3Buttons" "true"
    Option  "Emulate3Button" "10"
EndSection
```

the name 99-kensington.conf can be changed as long as it keeps the same format of 'number-text.conf'.

Identifier is not important.

MatchProduct is a substring of the device name. You get it by executing "xinput --list" (between ↳ and id=). If you only have one mouse, you do not need this.

ButtonMapping should be well known, the second digit is physical MIDDLE and is mapped to BACK (8). With Emulate3Button you can specify which physical button should be emulated, in this case physical 10. That is why the 10th number in ButtonMapping is MIDDLE (2). (0 means the button is disabled)

If you need more info: https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/4-evdev/